# validate user using firebase auth

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want that the users those who have signed up in user app cannot sign into the admin or doctors app.
Or the doctors those who have signed up in doctors app cannot sign into user or admin app.
Or the admin those who have signed up in admin app cannot sign into doctors or users app.

[image: database structure]

The method i tried for user validation is

```
private void updateUI(final FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user!=null){

        final DatabaseReference adminsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Admins").child(user.getUid());
        final DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());
        adminsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    userRole = dataSnapshot.child("role").getValue(String.class);
                    if (user.equals("admin")){
                        FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User already registered as an Admin",FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,FancyToast.INFO,false).show();
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        }
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                    else {
                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("Doctors").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("uid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        map.put("email", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                        map.put("name", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                        map.put("profile_status","incomplete");
                        map.put("role","doctor");
                        //map.put("location", getIntent().getExtras().get("location").toString());
                        userRef.updateChildren(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User details updated successfully", FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.SUCCESS, true).show();
                                } else {
                                    FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User details update unsuccessful", FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.SUCCESS, true).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    userRole = dataSnapshot.child("role").getValue(String.class);
                    if (userRole.equals("user")){
                        FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User already registered as a Customer",FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,FancyToast.INFO,false).show();
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        }
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                    else {
                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("Doctors").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("uid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        map.put("email", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                        map.put("name", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                        map.put("profile_status","incomplete");
                        map.put("role","doctor");
                        //map.put("location", getIntent().getExtras().get("location").toString());
                        userRef.updateChildren(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User details updated successfully", FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.SUCCESS, true).show();
                                } else {
                                    FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User details update unsuccessful", FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.SUCCESS, true).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing almost what needs to be done.
Just check if the user UID exists on Users child node or in admin child node using Data snapshot.

Here is how you can fetch the user role:

```
String userRole;

roleRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        roleRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                try {
                    userRole = dataSnapshot.child("role").getValue().toString();
                    userProf_username.setText(userNameInData);
                }catch (Throwable e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
```

Now the role of user is in the string userRole. So now you can check if user is admin or normal client.

Then add an if-else block:

```
if(userRole.equals("admin")){
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, adminActivity.class);
}
else{
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, userActivity.class);
}
```

Comment: What is user role?

Comment: @KunalShah userRole is what you fetch from the database. It is a string which contains the user roles whether he is client or admin

Comment: can you please provide complete code....as i am not getting you

Comment: @KunalShah i am typing the code. Till time please add this in your code. You need to add the user role. What the user is going to be during registration. Please add a new child in UID along with name, location, email and uid. Please can you do that?

Comment: @KunalShah this is I want you to do. Create a child with role like this at the time when your user registers [when you upload those other child like email and location]. See this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/r3qlgOw) and then use my code and there you go..

Comment: the child is not getting updated and the next activity is not getting started

Comment: @KunalShah can you share the output with me as well? So we can look the behaviour of app and get solution quickly

Comment: i removed the datasnapshot.exists() condition and it worked but the app got crashed with the below error:-     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: `map.put("role","doctor");` why did you put doctor here? You should add either client or admin based on who is registering. after adding this try creating a new user and send me his database data screenshot

Comment: i am not getting you

Comment: @KunalShah by chance you got telegram/instagram? For extended discussion with ease??

Comment: then ping me at @ dharmaraj_24 on either of those... I'll help there.. that'll be great

Comment: @KunalShah you still active on this topic? You need to show me your registration activity code and it's XML